# Dynamically Fill CSS Grid Based on Second Column Percentage Width

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm using CSS Grid and attempting to create a layout with two columns, one of them will have a percentage width and the other will dynamically fill based on what is set as the percentage width.

Am I over thinking this or is it not possible with CSS Grid?  I've done this within Flexbox so I'm not looking for any answers regarding that method.

```
<div class="grid-row">
  <div class="content">
  Page content here.
  </div>
  <aside class="sidebar">
  Sidebar content here.
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Well if one column has a % width, doesn't the second just have 100% less that amount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `grid-template-columns: X% 1fr`

```css
.grid-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 70% 1fr;
}

* {
  outline:1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-row">
  <div class="content">
  Page content here.
  </div>
  <aside class="sidebar">
  Sidebar content here.
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd also suggest that, instead of `%` unit, you use `fr` unit instead. It helps remove the guess work (and additional math) involved with using `%` values and works nicely with `gap` property. A good reference for `fr` unit in [CSS Trick article](https://css-tricks.com/introduction-fr-css-unit/)

Comment: Does this method have any overflow issues or as the last user mentioned any conflicts with the gap property?

Comment: Not with CSS-Grid. Flexbox has an overflow issue with `gap` but try it and see,

Comment: Doesn't seem to have an issue from my testing.  I figured it was something simple that I was overlooking.   I appreciate it.